# Python Poetry with Docker does't see requirements (with activated venv)

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-venv, python-poetry

while writing a minimal Dockerfile (for example) I encountered with problem, that my Poetry doesn't see my installed packages.

For the first time my Dockerfile looked like this:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.12.0
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base

RUN python -m pip install poetry

WORKDIR /app/

COPY ./pyproject.toml ./poetry.lock /app/

RUN poetry install --no-root

COPY ./app /app

EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application.
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

When I looked through the virtual environment that was created, all the dependencies were in it, cmd `poetry show` showed absolutely everything that was installed.

Looking through the sources of other projects and examples, I saw a line with disabling the creation of a virtual environment and added it to my dockerfile

```
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-root
```

But why does it work this way? Why is it worth disabling the creation of a virtual environment, what specifically prevents you from seeing dependencies in the container itself, when the virtual environment (as I looked) was immediately activated and the dependencies in it were?

Comment: Docker images are already a dedicated, isolated runtime context, no need to use virtual environments here. Just remember to create a real user, switch to that, _then_ run all your bootstrap commands. Right now, it looks like you're just running everything as root.

Answer (score 0):

The command as it is written does not take the virtual environment into account. I recommend to change to something like this:

```
CMD ["poetry", "run", "uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

---

> But why does it work this way? Why is it worth disabling the creation of a virtual environment, what specifically prevents you from seeing dependencies in the container itself, when the virtual environment (as I looked) was immediately activated and the dependencies in it were?

The issue is not about Docker or not Docker. When you need to decide if you should use a virtual environment or not, you should investigate if the non-virtual environment is shared with anything else or not.

Typically on Linux there is a Python that is used by the operating system itself, there are some libraries and applications pre-installed (by `apt` or `yum`). So you do not have a clean, empty environment to install your application(s) in. And there might be conflicts. That is why you should use a virtual environment.

Same thing in Docker containers, you need to investigate if the default environment already has things installed in it or not. And this might not be straightforward to do this investigation.

So my recommendation is to always use a virtual environment, so that there is no need to do this investigation. I doubt there is any meaningful drawback in using a virtual environment when it is not needed.

The argument that Docker already provides isolation so there is no need for a Python virtual environment is irrelevant, because we are talking about two different kinds of isolation. Those two constructs isolate from different things.